# Flutter localization fails on iPhone, Xcode

Tags: flutter, xcode, localization

I have created a simple Flutter application to check localization. The application supports Japanese and English. The application works fine and it does localize the application correctly.

***I have done following steps***

I add
**app_en.arb** and **app_ja.arb** files to **lib/l10n** folder

My **l10n.dart** file inside **lib/l10n** has the following

```
arb-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: app_en.arb
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart
```

My **pubspec.yamel** file has

```
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
    version: ^0.0.0

  intl: ^0.17.0
  provider: ^6.0.1

flutter:

  generate: true
```

when I run the application and  "**.dart_tool/flutter_gen/gen_l10n**" has 3 files

```
app_localizations.dart
app_localizations_en.dart
app_localizations_ja.dart
```

In my **info.plist** file I add 2 entries

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
  <string>en</string>
  <string>ja</string>
</array>
```

The application does work correctly.

However in Xcode Info tab, Localizations sections does not show the languages

[image]

I think I have done the localization correctly.

Not sure why the languages are not appearing there ...

Is there additional steps I have to do  ?

Comment: Can anyone provide some help on this?